# Call a javascript function from within a DetailsView

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

As below what client and/or server side code would allow a javascript function to be called within a DetailsView. It is just to open a modal popup.

```
<asp:DetailsView id="dv" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" AllowPaging="False">
<Fields>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:label runat="server" Text="Performance Status:"></asp:label>&nbsp;
            <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnwhostatus" runat="server">?</asp:LinkButton>--%>
            <%--<a id="btnwhostatus" href="">?</a>--%>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="lblPerformanceStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PerformanceStatus") %>' />                                                
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
```

```
function showWHO() {
$("#btnwhostatus").modalDialogTrigger({
        target: $('#whostatus'),
        title: 'Performance Status',
        width: '700px'
})};
```

Comment: Have you tried something like <asp:LinkButton ID="btnwhostatus" runat="server" OnClientClick="showWHO(); return false;">?</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: @Steve Greene Thank you for your reply. In the end I replaced the label and the hyperlink with a completely separate control, and that works fine.